# Using xmpp4r_facebook gem facebook chat message not being sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-chat

I am using `xmpp4r_facebook` gem to send a message to a facebook friend using my facebook application. Please note I have `xamp_login` permission. The problem is the message is not being sent. I have followed some other instructions from stackoverflow and implemented as they instructed. But still no message is being sent. Please note, to check, I have changed the facebook application sandbox mode off and make it live. But still not working.
Any help possible?

Or any other library suggestions can you provide?
please let me know!

```
sender_uid = current_user.uid
receiver_uid = TaggedPerson.last.uid.to_s
sender_chat_id = "-#{sender_uid}@chat.facebook.com"
receiver_chat_id = "-#{receiver_uid}@chat.facebook.com"
message_body = "message body"
message_subject = "message subject"

jabber_message = Jabber::Message.new(receiver_chat_id, message_body)
jabber_message.subject = message_subject

client = Jabber::Client.new(Jabber::JID.new(sender_chat_id))
client.connect
client.auth_sasl(Jabber::SASL::XFacebookPlatform.new(client,
                 ENV.fetch('APP_ID'), current_user.oauth_token,
                 ENV.fetch('SECRET_KEY')), nil)

# 0
client.send(jabber_message)
# nil
client.close
# nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use "Jabber::debug = true" and give more info?

Comment: oh I have solved this problem using a different gem. You can also see this gem. Its awesome: 
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/gems/facebook_chat

Comment: I actually experienced both gems and the xmpp4r_facebook was slightly better for my needs. I have to say none of them are 100% solid.
Not all the messages are actually being sent.

Comment: funniest thing is now its being sent on time :P

Comment: @IrfanAhmed - would be glad if you can update:
is this works for several users or only for yours ... ?

Comment: @IrfanAhmed mind letting us know if it's working well for you